# Convert second column to rows based on first column

Tags: python, csv

I've been looking for an answer to my problem but no success. I have a csv file with a large list of words that looks like this:

```
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
b 5
b 6
b 7
b 8
```

I need to convert it to this:

```
a 1 2 3 4
b 5 6 7 8
```

Does anybody have any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict` to store a list of numbers that match with each letter.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)

with open('input.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        let, num = line.rstrip().split()
        dd[let].append(num)

with open('out.csv', 'w') as fo:
    for k, v in dd.items():
        fo.write('%s %s\n' % (k, ' '.join(v)))
```

or you can use the csv module

```
import csv

...

with open('data2.txt') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter=' '):
        let, num = line[:2]
        dd[let].append(num)

...
```

You may lose order after this operation to recify that, either sort the keys when you build the output file (which gives you sorted order not original order).

```
with open('out.csv', 'w') as fo:
    for k in sorted(dd.keys()):
        fo.write('%s %s\n' % (k, ' '.join(dd[k])))
```

or just adapt the other answer to use `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: Fantastic, it solved my problem. I didn't try to sort the output however, because the tool I'm using this for doesn't require the list to be ordered in any way. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to want to compile a `dict` here.

```
d = {}
for row in csvdata:
    col1 = row[0]
    col2 = row[1]
    if col1 in d:
         d[col1].append(col2)
    else:
         d[col1] = [col2]
```

If you need to get the dict back into the list of lists format you mentioned you would just compile by looping through the keys of the dict.

```
outlists = []
for col1 in d:
    outlists.append([col1] + d[col1]) # Using '+' to concatenate lists.
```

I would imagine just using the dictionary, indexed by the keys from the first column, should be as, if not more, useful.